# RxJava2 | How to process a group Maybes

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I'm refactoring code to use RoomDataBase and RxJava2. I have a DataSource which fetches a row by id and returns a Maybe

```
 override fun getByAppWidgetId(appWidgetId: Int): Maybe<LocationWidget> {
    return mDB.locationDao().getByAppWidgetId(appWidgetId)
}
```

Elsewhere I get an array of `appWidgetId`s for which I want to get the row entries for each of the IDs. I want to combine all of the Maybes into a single Observable and

```
private fun hasCurrentLocationWidget(appWidgetIds: IntArray): Single<Boolean> {
  observableOfMaybes: Observable // something to hold the maybes we're about to get

  for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
    locationMaybe: Maybe<LocationWidget> = dataSource.getByAppWidgetId(appWidgetId)
    // -> add each Maybe to `observableOfMaybes`
  }

  return observableOfMaybes
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    // somehow return if any of the `isCurrentLocation` are true
    .filter({ location -> location.isCurrentLocation == true })
    .toSingle()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Observable of Maybes by using [`flatMapMaybe()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html). You would need to cast your `IntArray` to `vararg` for that.

```
Observable.fromArray(*appWidgetIds.toTypedArray())
        .flatMapMaybe { getByAppWidgetId(it) }
```

Comment: The problem is `it` is still an Array<Int> whereas it `getByAppWidgetId` expects `Int`s

Comment: That's why the `*` is there [kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

Comment: What is version of RxJava (or library) that contains flatMapMaybe call?

Comment: Both [RxJava 2](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapMaybe-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) and [RxJava 3](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#flatMapMaybe-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function-) have them